# How to use 'Expect' in JSBin template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsbin

Does anyone know how to use 'expect' function within JSBin template ?

[image]

The function which I have written on the page is just a sample one but the main priority is is resolve `"Reference error: expect is not defined"`

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: So, what libraries are you importing then? From where would you expect that is `expect` is coming? Which testing library are you hoping for?

Comment: @Icepickle I was following a tutorial in egghead.io & the author didn't mention any extra packages which imported in the same. As of now I tried to add a CDN in html section & which seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Then you might answer your own question with the imported cdn ;)

Comment: @Icepickle Sure .. :)

Answer (score 2):

Example of using `expect` in `jest`

https://jsbin.com/wapokahaxe/edit?html,console

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Running jest-expect-standalone</title>
  <!-- See https://github.com/valera-rozuvan/jest-expect-standalone -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jest-expect-standalone@latest/dist/expect.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    try {
      window.expect(true).toEqual(false);
      console.log('Test #1 passed!');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Test #1 failed!');
    }
    try {
      window.expect(2).toEqual(2);
      console.log('Test #2 passed!');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Test #2 failed!');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done by adding a CDN in the html section of the same JSBin. This method might be really helpful even if you can not find the required packages within the list of given packages

eg. `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/1.18.2/mocha.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library (which it appears you are), you will need to import it in order to use the methods exported by it

Comment: Yeah.. This might be helpful. Anyways, I managed to get it done by adding a CDN in html section of the same bin.